# Printing a NSTableView in Swift

Tags: swift, printing, nstableview

I'm trying to print a NSTableView. It is within a NSView. Tableview size is variable. I do not get to adapt the size of the controls. 
Can somebody help me?

Comment: What information about `NSTableView` are you interested in?

Comment: Is your `NSTableView` a property of your `NSView`?  Is it retained anywhere, or just added as a subview?  If you don't have a reference to the table view, you should be able to iterate through your `NSView`'s subviews and print the table view.

Comment: I have to print a fairly long list contained in a NSTableView .
For that I created a NSView and within the NSTableView have the data.
The number of rows is variable so I have to change every time the height of both the NSView and the NSTableView and once all data placed in the table (no scrolling ) . I have a button that prints the view.
This view , when passing production will not be visible.